# Excel not pulling all records from view

Tags: sql-server, excel

One of my users is trying to pull all the data from one of my views in SQL Server...   She's about 200 records short.  What gives?  I don't even know where to start troubleshooting this.  She's not using any filtering on the data, she's trying to pull it all using Excel's 'External Data' features.

I don't want to be spoon-fed, but I don't even know where to start looking to troubleshoot this.  If someone could point me in the right direction to begin my investigation, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: start with comparing what Excel is returning and what SQL has and see if there is something common.  Also, check w/ how your populating your excel worksheet. Did you hard code any row values? perhaps it's one of those "it'll never be more than 30000 records, so I'll hard code "a:a30000" and now you see there are actually 30472 records being returned.  Are all records being returned do your Object and only n-200 are being written vs the object only receiving n-2000,

Comment: 30,472 records, to be exact.

Comment: There is no chance anybody can offer you a solution here. We have absolutely no details to work with.

Comment: Step 1 - run the same query in a new spreadsheet. If you see all rows, then Step 2 - check the spreadsheet used. Anything hidden? Any filters? Step 3 - have user create a new spreadsheet and try again.

Comment: Nothing hidden, no filters, user created new spreadsheet and got the same results....

Comment: Any your code? Anything?

Comment: There's actually no code involved.  My colleague is using Excel's built in functions to connect to "my" SQL Server database instance, access the proper database, and query the proper dataset.  

There are no filters, and no other settings involved.

Comment: And now I just did the same thing myself with Excel, trying to pull from this one specific view, and am getting the same results.  It's pulling less than the full dataset...       Other tools (Power BI, Tableau) are pulling the full dataset.  Is there some sort of built-in limit in Excel?